# How to send json multipart data to php server in android

Tags: php, android, json, post, multipartform-data

I want to send name, email, phone number and a attached file to a php server in my android app. I want to send data's into a json array using post method. How it possible?

Comment: you should send data by multipart attached into body not json

Comment: Why? If the server wants to see json, then what would you do?

Comment: My server wants as json array.

Answer (score 0):

For multipart, what library did you use for your HTTP requests? Most libraries offer their own implementation for sending multipart data.

For sending data as a jsonarray, try looking into GSON implementation.